# Expo Android there is a white flicker when switching from bottom tab navigator to material top tab navigator

Tags: javascript, expo, react-native, react-native-navigation

[White flicker when switching from bottom tab navigator to top tab navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIcSK.gif)

This white flicker is much more noticeable outside of this gif. But I am using an **Expo** managed React Native project and when I switch from my Bottom tab navigator to my Top tab navigator the screen flickers white. This issue only occurs on **Android**. On top of that, when you press a TextInput to open the keyboard, the screen turns white in the section the keyboard takes up while the keyboard animation is occuring. Here are my navigators in App.js

```
const AuthTabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
const AuthStackScreen = () => (
      <AuthTabs.Navigator tabBarOptions={options}>
          <AuthTabs.Screen name="Sign In" component={SignInScreen} />
          <AuthTabs.Screen name="Sign Up" component={SignUpScreen} />
      </AuthTabs.Navigator>
    );
```

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
  const MainStack = () => (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Deals" component={DealsStackScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Categories" component={CategoriesStackScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="My Account" component={MyAccountStackScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
```

```
  const RootStack = createStackNavigator();
  const Root = () => (
      <RootStack.Navigator headerMode="none" cardStyle={{opacity: 1}} >
          <RootStack.Screen name="Home" component={MainStack}/>
          <RootStack.Screen name="Auth" component={AuthStackScreen}/>
      </RootStack.Navigator>
  );
```

```
    return (
      <AuthContextProvider>
        <NavigationContainer theme={{ colors: {background: `${Colors.surface}` }}}>
          <Root />
        </NavigationContainer>
      </AuthContextProvider>
    );
```

I tried adding my theme color to the `NavigationContainer` but this did not fix the issue. Also link shows the GIF of what is happening.

Comment: Put a wrapper view around the root of your app and set a background color that you want to be visible when this happens.

Comment: @brentvatne Exactly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have to wrap your RootStack around a View with backgroundColor as theme's backgroundColor

Your `RootStack` would look something like this now

```
import { useTheme } from '@react-navigation/native';

... 

const { colors } = useTheme();

const RootStack = createStackNavigator();

const Root = () => (
  <View style={{ flex:1, backgroundColor: colors.background }}> // This is the catch..Also it needs flex:1
    <RootStack.Navigator headerMode="none" cardStyle={{ opacity: 1 }}>
      <RootStack.Screen name="Home" component={MainStack} />
      <RootStack.Screen name="Auth" component={AuthStackScreen} />
    </RootStack.Navigator>
  </View>
);
```

Comment: When I wrapped it with the View my entire screen just went white. I also tried adding the theme like I have in NavigationContainer to RootStack.Navigator but that didn't work either

Comment: Also give the View a flex of 1...Check answer again

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you think your problem is solved, consider acccepting the answer for other users who run into this problem so that it can help them..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

for me how i had to set the theme on the navigation container

```
const navigationTheme = {
    ...DefaultTheme,
    colors: {
      ...DefaultTheme.colors,
      background: 'red, //your color here
    },
  };
```

then

```
    <NavigationContainer theme={navigationTheme}>
```