# React Native Chat Input - How to Avoid keyboard?

Tags: react-native, expo, android-softkeyboard

My project uses expo and react native
I'm having problems to handle keyboard in my chat screen:

Setting "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan" on app.json makes the screen slides up an header desappears.
Setting "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "resize" on app.json makes the screen jump, doesn't slide the messages up (what I want to do) and the app flashes white background every time de keyboard opens and closes.

How should I make the input and messages slide up with the keyboard, keeping the header still?

I've tried to use KeyboardAvoidingView, KeyboardAwareScrollview in multiple ways but none of then gave me te expected result.

Comment: On Android those are the only two options-  resize or pan.  It's part of the OS-  how the app reacts when the keyboard comes up.  You want resize, but if you're getting a white flash like that its just because ReactNative redraws too slowly.  On a real native app you wouldn't have a problem.  So unless you have a slow initialization before render that you can drastically speed up, there's not much you can do about it.

Comment: thanks for the explanation... I'm trying to change app's bakground-color so the white flash wont be visible. Maybe I should make the app real native

Comment: For the white flash part, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67014341/expo-android-there-is-a-white-flicker-when-switching-from-bottom-tab-navigator-t/67318189#67318189) answer.

Comment: if you guys are interested, check my answer. I found a solution

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it perfectly just like whatsapp using this awesome lib:

https://kirillzyusko.github.io/react-native-keyboard-controller/

Comment: not working on expo go